# VisualStudio: Shortcut for when Renaming Variable

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio, when you rename a variable name in its definition, there's a little underline in the last letter so if you hover that, you'll get the option "Rename OldVaribleName to NewVariableName" and so rename all entries in that procedure of that variable.

Is there a shortcut for that and not use the mouse?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By way of an updated answer...

**Update for Visual Studio 2022**

Same behavior as 2019.

**Update for Visual Studio 2019**

Same behavior as 2017.

**Update for Visual Studio 2017**

In Visual Studio 2017 click the variable and then press `Ctrl + r, r`. This works without an issue (see comments below about differences in Visual Studio 2015 where the whole command had to be repeated).

**Visual Studio 2015**

In Visual Studio 2015, if you click on the variable and use `Ctrl + r, Ctrl + r` it will lock onto the variable name and highlight all instances of the variable. Then as you begin typing the new variable name it will rename all instances at once. Hit enter to escape, once you are finished (note: differences might exist between update versions. See comments below).

Edit: One warning on this approach. If you are using Razor in your views, it will not necessarily rename those variables. I haven't done an empirical experiment to see if there are certain cases where it does or does not pick those up, but I have definitely had several cases where it renamed the more strongly typed variables in the server-side code (DAL and Controllers) but not the views.

Comment: It's actually Ctrl + R, R (you don't have to Ctrl that second R but you can).  F2 still works but I prefer Ctrl + R, R. Using F2 forces me to glance down at the keyboard.

Comment: @JasonEnochs I actually tried just Ctrl + R, R on my VS 2015 Professional and it doesn't work. I have to hit the Ctrl + R 2x for some reason. If you right click the variable and look at the `Rename` feature, it also says `Ctrl + R, Ctrl + R`. Not sure why it's different between machines.

Comment: Hmm, I have 2015 Enterprise and it's Ctrl + R, R on my machine (actually works both ways).  This Microsoft link also it should be Ctrl + R, R.  http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/  Either way, it still beats F2.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017. `Ctrl+r`takes me to the solution explorer, then pressing `r` again takes me to the first file starting with an r.. `F2` open the object browser.. what is wrong with me? :')

Comment: @Ama when installing Visual Studio it usually asks which default mappings you want to use. Options include Visual Studio, Vim, Emacs, etc. Yours sounds like the wrong mappings are applied. Maybe check your  mappings in the options?

Comment: I see, in `Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard` had the Visual Basic 6 mapping scheme enabled. Switched it to Visual C# 2005 and it works like a charm!

Comment: @Ama great! :-D

Comment: Firstly tried pressing `Ctrl+Shift+r`, `Ctrl+Shift+r`  because you've wrote uppercase `R`, but in VS2019 works `Ctrl+r`,`Ctrl+r`.

Comment: @V.7 fair enough. I edited to lowercase r to avoid confusion.

Comment: In Razor views, strongly-typed references to the variable are only renamed if the file is currently open in a tab (from what I've observed in VS2019).

Answer (score 71):

These are known as Smart Tags.

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> is another option.

Comment: Neither of them works for me (VS2012). Do I have to activate Smart Tags somehow..?

Comment: I'm wondering if this is very language or version dependent. None of the solutions do anything for me in MSVS C++ 2010.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in MS VS Express 2013 (neither 2012) in JavaScript mode (when making Windows Phone apps).

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013 this is now [refactoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxxabwd.aspx) using CTRL+R for C#. Uncertain regarding other programming languages.

Comment: Yeah CTRL+R and then CTRL+R is a quickly way to rename variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/rename?view=vs-2019

Comment: This works in Visual Studio Code, refactoring in Visual Studio (2017 & 2019 at least) is `Ctrl+R, R`

Answer (score 16):

Depending on what the default keyboard mapping scheme you use, you might be able to get away with simply pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to call **Rename** before ever typing in the text change.

If your version of VS does not have the <kbd>F2</kbd> mapped, you can rename that from within the program's Main Menu:

- **Tools** >> **Options**
- In Options Dialog, expand **Environment**, and then select **Keyboard**
- Type `File.Rename` into the *"Show commands containing"* Search box
- Select the "Press Shortcut keys" TextBox and click <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Click **Assign**

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is nice, but the question is about variable renaming, not file renaming.

Comment: @basher - after setting this up, all you need to do is press F2 if you want to rename a variable. The global command is called **File.Rename**, but since you are within a text editing window of a code editor, renaming the file would not be allowed anyway. So, this maps the rename command to renaming the variable.

Comment: ha! nice. Wouldn't have thought based on that name. I dig the F2 shortcut idea for it as that's what windows typically uses.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 I had to assign it not to "File.Rename" but to "Refactor.Rename", then it worked.

Comment: In VS 2017 'Refactor.Rename' is set to `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R (Global)`, and 'File.Rename' set to `F2 (Team Explorer)`. However none of them work for me..

Answer (score 14):

Ctrl + h 
work for me 
Good luck

Comment: I know this is old and not the accepted answer, but for those coming here from google and perhaps having trouble with the other answers, I would avoid using this approach for a few reasons.  This is just doing "Search and Replace" like you would in any text editor.  **It's completely unaware of where your variable is used and may rename things you don't intend it to.**  Be cautious if you use this.  Understand that you need to double check what it replaces.

Answer (score 6):

In VS 2008 using C# you can just hit <kbd>F2</kbd>, not sure about other versions/languages, though.  That also renames files in Windows Explorer if you're too lazy to right-click like I am.

Comment: This is the most convenient way for me to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: valid for US keyboards only ), a French AZERTY keyboard, by e.g. the "." results in a "Shift"+";" combination and does not work in VS.

Comment: @serhio: Using a french AZERTY keyboard, the default shortcut is `Ctrl` + `;`

Answer (score 4):

If you like, I would suggest that you try [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), it provides a lot of functionality for refactoring your code.

In ReSharper to rename a variable or function, simply use the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>.

(I know it may not be an answer to your question, but I think if you like using keyboard shortcuts that you will enjoy ReSharper).

Answer (score 3):

On Visual Studio 2013, the listed shortcuts `Ctrl`+`.` , `F2`, etc... did not work for me.

I found that installing a [Visual C++ Refactoring](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/164904b2-3b47-417f-9b6b-fdd35757d194?SRC=Home) extension solved my problem.

I can now use `Ctrl`+`R`, which brings up a refactoring pop-up and allows me to select current scope by default, as well as other instances in the same file.

[image: Refactoring PopUp]

Here's an example of a variable I renamed in a function. There was another function there with the same variable name, which it suggests to rename...

[image: Refactoring Menu]

Comment: Excellent!! Working for me (In VS2013)

Answer (score 1):

Quick Notes:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> works. **But not if you hit backspace and then rename the variable name.**

e.g.
rename **S**enderEmail to **s**enderEmail

If you highlight the **S** in **S**enderEmail and replace the letter and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> you will see the popup to rename the variable. If you add a letter to the variable this still works. If you delete, it still works.

However, and this is what I do a lot - if you hit backspace on the **S**enderEmail and make it enderEmail and then add an **s** making it **s**enderEmail and then hit Ctrl + . this will not work.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> also works in the same way.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

For windows installation you need to double click the variable name (it will highlight all the instances) then press alt and double click the variables where you want to rename.
Your will get all  teh cursors and now you can delete the old name and give new name.

Answer (score 0):

After the rename: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Before the rename: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>

*VS 2017, Smart Tags enabled*

Answer (score 0):

Searched for this in 2019... What worked for me was to go to Options and add the shortcut on the Refactor.Rename command, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqBM1.png)

Answer (score -2):

I use `ctrl` + `f`

It opens a window you can use to find and replace all occurrences of a word. You can replace the word in "Current Document", "All Open Documents", "Current Project", or "Entire Solution" with the drop down menu below the button that says "Replace All" when you hoover over it.

I hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: The point of the rename refactoring function is that it renames based on the symbol ie the variable name, so it would only rename the variable based on it's scope and usage, not a text match.

Comment: Most users will know how to use a find/replace. The question in my opinion is clearly asking the shortcut for renaming that particular variable within that particular scope and having it apply throughout that scope, like Alt+Shift+R in Eclipse.