# What is the easiest way to implement a naming convention on an existing project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, naming-conventions, standards

I have just inherited a project that is a little bit of a labyrinth - there is no naming convention either, which makes it difficult to parse. It's incredibly frustrating to misread a line because of this and waste an hour or two.

Is there an automated way to, for instance, ensure all methods have a capital letter, all public variables have a capital letter and all private variables are prefixed by an underscore?

I would do it myself, but the project is large and it would not be an effective use of time.

What advice can you give me for coping with this, short of "suck it up!" ? :)

The project is in C#, and I am using VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partially automate your code cleanup if you happen to have [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (you should! No, really, if you don't have it RUN to get your copy), [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/), and the [StyleCop for Resharper](http://stylecop.forresharper.org/) plugin. Setting up everything (defining StyleCop rules et all) is probably a non-trivial task though. So depending on your code base size, this might or might not be a profitable investment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience on refactoring, but the first solution comes to my mind is the useful **Rename** feature VS2010, to rename the members of your project.

[image: Rename Feature]

In this way, you can rename, for example, starting from its definition, all the references to a variable.
This feature is also discussed [here](http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2010/03/rename-feature-in-visual-web-developer.html) and in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098654/visualstudio-shortcut-for-when-renaming-variable). Maybe, you have to change the definition of a lot of members, but, in this way, you can save so much time than using the **Find & Replace**.

Also, probably, the best tool to achieve your goal is [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), used to refactor the C# code. My colleagues used it to refactor and improve the code. Something about ReSharper is also discussed in SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433654/how-to-reformat-naming-styles-with-resharper?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192993/resharper-rename-feature-similar-to-visual-studio-rename-is-it-possible).